# Has anyone ported a standard toolkit onto pepper?

Tags: google-nativeclient

I was wondering if anyone has ported a standard toolkit like gdk (gtk), qt (kde) or fltk to the pepper api? Or written a cross platform api that includes pepper? I would like to write my code to work with both X11 and nacl.

Answer (score 1):

There is a QT port here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_Google_Native_Client

It looks like it hasn't been updated in a year, though, so it may have some rough edges.